# SQLite Enquiring only specific thing from DB

Tags: python, sqlite

I have created a database in sqlite which looks like this

```
employeeID    Name       email                Age
1             Darshan    darshan@example.com  24
2             Anja       anja@example.com     22
3             Neeta      neeta@gmail.com      28
4             Michelle   m@gmail.com          32
```

So for enquiring by searching for ID I use this code

```
ID = 1
c.execute("SELECT * FROM employee WHERE employeeID=:employeeID",[ID])
print(c.fetchall())
conn.close
```

which returns me this, which is great as wanted

```
1             Darshan    darshan@example.com  24
```

but is it possible to only return me an email ID or just Age from this?

Comment: only select the wanted column like `SELECT Age FROM ....`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. Can you put this as answer. So i can say it as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the returned columns in the SQL statement like this for the `Age` column:

```
SELECT Age FROM employee WHERE ...
```